# Install Characters With C# Installer?

Tags: c#, fonts, installation, character

I have a little problem. I would like to use a custom made character in a project I'm working on (in c#). I could create the character in the private character editor program, but I was thinking of making an c# installer for my project. So my question I pose would be how can I install a character(s) to a computer through a c# installer?

Comment: Have you search for any tutorial? Have you tried anything? If yes, mention it on your question and point out on which step did you fail.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. If by character you mean a letter/glyph, that is not a thing that exists "on its own". Are you asking how to create a font in C# and then use that? Because the most obvious answer of course is "why? just make that font, bundle it with your software, and read it in from your program's associated `%AppData%` dir." Don't install things that you custom made specifically for your application at the system level, that's a really shitty thing to do to your users.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You will want to install the font in the fonts folder using the installer.

Afterwards, you will want to check for it and install it in your program's bootstrap.
https://brutaldev.com/post/Installing-and-removing-fonts-using-C

The easy way out: Unless you are consistently changing text or accepting user inputs in this custom font, it might be better to store and display it in an image.